# SharePoint Apps 404

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio-2013, dns

I have a problem with SharePoint Apps. I tried to configure SharePoint to work with apps but after following all the steps, i created a app, i press Start in VS and my browser answered with

> 404 - file or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable

[image]

I followed the following [instructions](http://sharepoint.softwaredevelopmentoutpost.com/2013/10/create-isolated-app-domain-in.html)

From what i can think of, i think it is a issue with DNS but im not sure about it. Can someone help me with this?
(My environment have the following settings: Server1(DC and SQL Server) Server2(SharePoint Server)).
Thanks!

Comment: any other clue in ULS logs or Event logs? because this is very much generic error.

Comment: Nope :( uls view doesn't show any error. On most blogs, they say that you should create another web application on port 80, but sharepoint doesn't allow me to create another one on that port.